# Facing Expected atom at position error in regular expression

Tags: javascript, reactjs, regex, npm, babeljs

I have a form in react application and i want to allow foreign characters including English in the input field. I am using this regular expression `const alphabetRegex = /^([A-Za-z]+ )+[A-Za-z]+$|^[A-Za-z]*\p{L}/gu;`
But when i try to test, it is giving an error in the console like

```
 Expected atom at position 37
    A-Za-z]*\p{L}
```

I tried using `npm install --save-dev @babel/plugin-proposal-unicode-property-regex` and

```
{
  "plugins": ["@babel/plugin-proposal-unicode-property-regex"]
}
```

in .babelrc file.

How can I resolve this and make it work to allow foreign characters?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

Have you checked your Babel version to be current?

Comment: I tried using the latest babel but no use

Comment: @ShivakumarH.G Older Babel versions are known to crash with "\p{}". Maybe you could try Babel's slack https://slack.babeljs.io/ for help or transpile your regex with https://mothereff.in/regexpu